# Do I lose my local git branches on reinstalling git?

Tags: git

Do I lose my local branches when I uninstall git and install it later again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no.

You can uninstall git, but as long as you don't delete your project's `.git` folder, you never lose anything.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in git is stored in the .git folder of your repository and therefore independent of your git installation. As long as you don't delete any folder named .git you can do anything you want without losing your branches and history.